# user systemd service cannot find system service

Tags: linux, systemctl, avahi

I have a service running under user (in terms of systemctl):

```
[Unit]
Requires=avahi-daemon.socket
After=NetworkManager.service network.service pipewire-pulse.service org.gnome.Shell@wayland.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/exec.sh
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=gnome-session.target
```

it fails to start due to: `Unit avahi-daemon.socket not found`, but it is active and running.

I suppose, it is because avahi-daemon is running as a system service and my service is running under user session.
Could anyone explain what am I doing wrong?

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: A user service can't "see" system services. They are unable to start/stop/query system services. I think you can be confident that `avahi-daemon.socket` will be available before your service starts, but if you find that's not true you could use an `ExecStartPre` to wait until it's available.